# node: persist data after process termination

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm using [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache) to cache data from a CLI application that observes changes in files and caches them to avoid new data processing.

the problem is that I noticed that this cache is destroyed on each command, since each time the tool is called in the terminal a new instance is generated and the old one is destroyed. probably, the data is also destroyed.

I need to keep, for a specific TTL, two things in cache/memory, even if the process ends:

- the processed data
- the specific instance of fs.watcher, watching and executing caching operations

the question is: how do i do it? I've been searching for days on the internet and trying alternatives and I can't find a solution.

Comment: There are things that can persist after processes terminates. They are called files. Everyone uses files to persist data: databases (mysql, oracle, mongodb etc.), configuration systems, Microsoft Word. Photoshop, git etc.

Comment: ☝ this. Save everything into a file after your command is done, and read the file at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to keep ... things in cache/memory, even if the process ends

That's, pretty much by definition, not possible. When a process terminates, all its resources are freed up for use by something else (barring a memory-leak bug in the OS itself).

It sounds like you need to refactor your app into a service that can run in the background and separate front-end that can communicate with it.